# Material Design Dimensions in Flutter

Tags: material-design, flutter

I'm new to flutter and I want to make an application like WhatsApp
I decided to know design dimensions and I went [to](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#specs)
I found the dimensions in dps when I applied the stated dimensions on the app bar [this was the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8apZy.png) while [this is the original app bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zshlc.png), so how can I apply material design dimensions (dps, px, etc...) in Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All material design widgets in Flutter satisfies material design guidelines by default. For example a Floating action button comes with a default marigin witch you don't need to specify manually. So you don't need to provide custom padding or marigin to your appbar action items.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap any widget in a `Container`. Than you can set width and height if it has none.

A lot of widgets do have it though.

For example, IconButton that you can put in actions of AppBar has iconSize

```
          IconButton(iconSize: 36.0,icon: Icon(Icons.search,));
```

But if you want asymmetrical touch field you can combine few widgets together

```
          InkWell(
              child: new Container(
                width: 36.0,
                height: 24.0,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                ),
              ));
```

There are many combinations available, so its best to ask specific question for a specific component.